# is this ISBN-10 Checksum calculation in php correct?

Tags: php, isbn

I have found a PHP script  [github ISBN-Calc Routine](https://gist.github.com/r15ch13/5459442) to perform the ISBN-10 checksum calculation:

```
<?php
/**
 * Calculate ISBN checksum
 * 
 * @param string $isbn
 * @return integer
 */
function isbn_checksum($isbn) {
    $sum = 0; $isbn = str_split(preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $isbn));
    foreach($isbn as $key => $z) {
        if($key >= 12) break;
        $sum += ($key % 2) ? $z * 3 : $z;
    }
    $checksum = (10 - $sum % 10);
    return ($checksum == 10) ? 0 : $checksum;
}
```

But f.e for my `ISBN-10: 0470173424`  I get `Checksum: 0`with this github script.

Accoring to [ISBN online checker](http://www.hahnlibrary.net/libraries/isbncalc.html) the checksum should be 4 as is it in the ISBN. Can anyone here provide me with the correct PHP routine, please?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried to debug this? If the script does not work as expected, choose another - the algorithm is pretty simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previously marked answer is close but incomplete.

Specifically this portion:

```
$check = 11 - ($sum % 11); // This can output 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 not 0
return ($check === 10) ? 'X' : $check; // This is incomplete does not address 11
```

The code does not deal with the situation where 11 - 0 = 11. I have tried to clarify it below.

```
function isbn10($isbn)
{
  $isbn = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $isbn);
  $digits = str_split(substr($isbn, 0, 9));

  $sum = 0;

  foreach ($digits as $index => $digit)
  {
      $sum += (10 - $index) * $digit;
  }

  $check = 11 - ($sum % 11);

  // $check may hold either 10 or 11, but not 0
  // 10 becomes X, 11 becomes 0 -- output is 1 character only
  if ($check == 10)
  {
    $check = 'X';
  }
  elseif ($check == 11)
  {
    $check = '0';
  }

  return $check;
}
```

An example ISBN where the earlier answer fails is 0134093410

Answer (score 2):

That function is for calculating an ISBN-13 check digit, not ISBN-10 - that's why it breaks the loop after the 12th character.

The algorithm for ISBN-10 is different, and requires multiplying the first 9 digits of the number by 10 down to 2. The difference between that sum and the next multiple of 11 is the check-digit. For your example, this would be:

(10 * 0) +
(9 * 4) +
(8 * 7) +
(7 * 0) +
(6 * 1) +
(5 * 7) +
(4 * 3) +
(3 * 4) +
(2 * 2) = **161**.

The next multiple of 11 is 165, so the check-digit should be 4 (as you say). In the case where the check-digit would be 10, X is used. We can model this in PHP like this:

```
function isbn10($isbn) {
    $isbn = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $isbn);
    $digits = str_split(substr($isbn, 0, 9));

    $sum = 0;

    foreach ($digits as $index => $digit) {
        $sum += (10 - $index) * $digit;
    }

    $check = 11 - ($sum % 11);

    return ($check === 10) ? 'X' : $check;
}

echo isbn10('047017342');
```

> 4

You can see this working here: https://eval.in/1039654

Answer (score -1):

There is an library from **GitHub**: https://github.com/Fale/isbn

There is a function called **"Check"**:

**Initialization:**

```
$isbn = new Isbn\Isbn();
```

**Check values:** (Example)

```
$isbn->check->is10('888183718'); // Will return false
$isbn->check->is13('9788889527191'); // Will return true
$isbn->check->is13('978888952719'); // Will return false
```

You can download the library from the given link.

Maybe that helps a bit.

Have a nice weekend!

Answer (score -1):

> If you want to check if the ISBN-10 is correct

**Validate ISBN-10**

```
<?php
function isValidIsbn10($isbn) {
    $check = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        if ('x' === strtolower($isbn[$i])) {
            $check += 10 * (10 - $i);
        } elseif (is_numeric($isbn[$i])) {
            $check += (int)$isbn[$i] * (10 - $i);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return (0 === ($check % 11)) ? 1 : false;
}

var_dump( isValidIsbn10('0470173424') );
```

*Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14096142/5201919*

**Will show**

> 1 for true

**Demo**

https://eval.in/1053913

Comment: You copied this from somewhere, cite your sources.